# Are there any reasons an SSIS Lookup Transformation would give 0 output rows, neither matched or un-matched?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

I'm debugging an SSIS package locally in VS2019. I have an odd behavior where a lookup transform against a cache is receiving 22 rows on the input, but both the 'Match' and 'No Match' outputs are showing 0 rows. It does work sometimes, but only when data from an unrelated branch in the flow is not present.
Are there reasons why a lookup would not include rows in either output? Or is this some kind of local execution bug?

Answer (score 1):

what you mean by both the 'Match' and 'No Match' outputs are showing 0 rows?

Let's make a sample data and analyze the situation:

This is a Flat File Source data by branch:

[image: Flat File Source Data]

Then connect this source data to LookUp Transformation.

Critical step is what to do with no-matching data (A good option is to send rows to no-match OLEDB Table)

[image: No-Matching Data]

On the connection Tab, Full-Cache Mode data corresponds to a table on a SQL Server DB

[image: DFE]

[image: SQL-DB]

Join them by branch, and add manager to Pipeline:

[image: LookUp]

Then send matched and non-matched records to 2 separate OLEDB destinations by designing tables in your local server:

End Result:
[image: LookUp Transform]

Now Lets check Match and Unmatched destination table :

Matched Records

[image: MATCHED_OLEDB DEST]

Unmatched Records:

[image: Unmatched Records]

Comment: Thanks for the example. What I meant was exactly as stated, 22 rows go in, 0 rows go out. No matched, no unmatched.  This was while debugging in VS.  When running in production the same package works, so I'm guessing it was some odd issue with running local in VS. It wasn't even related to what I was trying to investigate.